# Intellij copying text from different lines

Tags: intellij-idea, editor, editing, multiline

There's a feature in notepad++ where you can pick of snippets from different lines & paste them in one go. Is there anything similar in Idea IntellIJ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature yet, you can [vote for it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80056) in YouTrack.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use a clipboard manager outside of your current application. ClipX is a good one on Windows. Glipper or equivalent is good on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the feature that approaches that the most is the multi-clipboard.
Copy each of your lines independently, and then paste them using `CTRL-SHIFT-V`.